# Use Python package installed with apk in Alpine Linux

Tags: python, numpy, docker, alpine-linux

I'd like to install some Python packages in Alpine Linux using apk. I use numpy as an example in the following.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3-alpine
RUN apk add --update py3-numpy
```

I build my Docker image

```
$ docker build -t python-numpy .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/2 : FROM python:3-alpine
 ---> 930a7e894675
Step 2/2 : RUN apk add --update py3-numpy
 ---> Running in b30470090cde
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.10/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.10/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/6) Installing libgcc (8.3.0-r0)
(2/6) Installing libquadmath (8.3.0-r0)
(3/6) Installing libgfortran (8.3.0-r0)
(4/6) Installing openblas (0.3.6-r0)
(5/6) Installing python3 (3.7.3-r0)
(6/6) Installing py3-numpy (1.16.4-r1)
Executing busybox-1.30.1-r2.trigger
OK: 113 MiB in 41 packages
Removing intermediate container b30470090cde
 ---> 5a82ffa67522
Successfully built 5a82ffa67522
Successfully tagged python-numpy:latest
```

run it and try to import the package in python

```
$ docker run -it --rm python-numpy python -c "import numpy"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

However, it is not found. Running `pip install numpy` after `apk add --update py3-numpy` does not consider the apk package `py3-numpy` and downloads another version:

```
Collecting numpy
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/da/32/1b8f2bb5fb50e4db68543eb85ce37b9fa6660cd05b58bddfafafa7ed62da/numpy-1.17.0.zip (6.5MB)
...
```

If I specify the same version as of `py3-numpy` (see output of `docker build`) in `pip install numpy==1.16.4-r1`, it leads to

```
Collecting numpy==1.16.4-r1
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy==1.16.4-r1 (from versions: 1.3.0, 1.4.1, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.6.0, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3, 1.10.0.post2, 1.10.1, 1.10.2, 1.10.4, 1.11.0b3, 1.11.0rc1, 1.11.0rc2, 1.11.0, 1.11.1rc1, 1.11.1, 1.11.2rc1, 1.11.2, 1.11.3, 1.12.0b1, 1.12.0rc1, 1.12.0rc2, 1.12.0, 1.12.1rc1, 1.12.1, 1.13.0rc1, 1.13.0rc2, 1.13.0, 1.13.1, 1.13.3, 1.14.0rc1, 1.14.0, 1.14.1, 1.14.2, 1.14.3, 1.14.4, 1.14.5, 1.14.6, 1.15.0rc1, 1.15.0rc2, 1.15.0, 1.15.1, 1.15.2, 1.15.3, 1.15.4, 1.16.0rc1, 1.16.0rc2, 1.16.0, 1.16.1, 1.16.2, 1.16.3, 1.16.4, 1.17.0rc1, 1.17.0rc2, 1.17.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for numpy==1.16.4-r1
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried `python3`? `docker run -it --rm python-numpy python3 -c "import numpy"`

Comment: @JohnKeyes Yes, same result.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The issue is that `python:3-alpine` has two Pythons: the one provided by Alpine, and an additional one added by the Python Docker image. Installing packages in one will not be reflected in the other.

Some options:

1. Switch to just alpine base image, `FROM alpine:3.10`. Then you'll just have the Python installed via apk.
2. Stop using Alpine, and switch to `FROM python:3.7-slim-buster` (my personal recommendation: https://pythonspeed.com/articles/base-image-python-docker-images/). This will allow you to pip install numpy without having to compile anything—binary wheels don't work on Alpine, but will work on the (Debian) Buster image.

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT:** This approach is not recommended, since the apk packages are for a different python version (see [Itamar Turner-Trauring's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57446376/1065654)).

---

apk installs python packages in `/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages`. This path is not part of Python's `sys.path` (in Docker images). Hence, packages installed with apk are not found. The installation directory has to be added to the [search path](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH):

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine
RUN apk add --update py3-numpy
ENV PYTHONPATH /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages
```

Note that there is no `/usr/lib/python3/site-packages` and even if you use `python:3.6-alpine`, `apk add --update py3-numpy` creates a directory `/usr/lib/python3.7` and not `/usr/lib/python3.6`.

---

By the way, you have a similar issue if you are using `python:3`, but the installation directory is different

```
FROM python:3
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3-numpy
ENV PYTHONPATH /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
```

Answer (score 0):

Install it as python package will work fine as the base image is python so I will recommend you to install it as a python package. As installing with the alpine package manager it does not exist in the python packages nor in alpine packages. So below will work fine.

```
FROM python:3-alpine
RUN apk add g++  && \\ 
pip install numpy
```

Now run the container

```
docker run -it --rm abc python -c "import numpy"
```

Comment: Thanks, but I actually like to know how to use the package that is installed by apk.